# Case of names of built-in JavaScript types

Tags: javascript, naming, built-in-types

In JavaScript, `typeof 0` gives `'number'` not `'Number'`, but `instanceof 0 Number`.

Would it be accurate to say the canonical names of the built-in types are capitalized, and the lowercase return value of `typeof` is a quirk/inconsistency that can't be changed for historical reasons, but would be changed if it could be? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Dunno, but the convention in Javascript is for consructors to start with a capital letter, and Number is a constructor (or strictly, is a function that can be called as a constructor), hence the capitalisation. Note that `typeof new Number()` returns `object`. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

Actually number is the built-in value type where Number is an object.

If you say typeof there's no need to temporarily convert 0 to an Object.

If you use instanceof, it temporarily converts 0 to an object.

This is similar to what you do with a string:

`"sometest"` => This is a string

However, if you would do `"sometest".toLowerCase()` it will first (temporarily) convert the string to a String-object and then call the method on that object (since value-types can't have methods).

In short, lowercase means value-type, uppercase means object

Comment: Well, the difference here is between object-types and value-types. If you take a look at section 4.3.9 to 4.3.21 you'll see that are are null-types and null-values, boolean-types and boolean-values, ... What is a bit confusing is the fact that they don't use the uppercase and lowercase consistently in the spec.

Comment: It consistently uses "Number type" though, the lower case "number type" isn't used in ES5. It also consistently uses *Type(x)* in the pseudo–code. I deleted my earlier comment as it was out of context: the quote was referring to specification types, not types in general.